# Finding the area of a rectangle and a square java

Tags: java

I would like your help with my assignment.

I need to find the area and perimeter of a square/rectangle. I was able to get the area and perimeter of a rectangle, but I dont know how to include that in a case or switch `.

Please find below my code.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
class shape
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double length = 0;
        double width = 0;
        double perimeter = 0;
        double area = 0;    

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter length of rectangle");
        length = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter width of rectangle");
        width = sc.nextDouble();

        area = length * width;
        perimeter = 2*(length+width);
        System.out.println("Area of rectangle is : "+area);
        System.out.println("Perimeter of rectangle is : "+perimeter);
    }
}
```

Comment: `i do not know how to include that in a case or switch` I can´t really tell what your question is, please clearify.

Comment: What exactly is the question? To my understanding, the implementation calculates the area and perimeter correctly, which can also be used to calculate the area and perimeter of a square. Please describe the logic you wish to implement.

Comment: Write a java application to find the area and perimeter of square and rectangle. The program must consist four different classes. One is the parent class called shape with consist of attributes such as length and width and the constructor class while the second is the child class called square which calculates the area and perimeter of the square shape while third is a child class called rectangle to find the same area and parameter for the rectangle.

Comment: The task asks you to create 4 classes - you created 1. Are you asking how to create a class?

Comment: This question is not clear at all. Plese read the how to ask section and specify your problem. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started

```
System.out.println("perimeter (p) or area (a) ?");      
char ch = sc.next().charAt(0);
switch(ch)
{
    case 'a':
        System.out.println("Area of rectangle is : "+area);
        break;
    case 'p':
        System.out.println("Perimeter of rectangle is : "+perimeter);
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Area of rectangle is : "+area);
        System.out.println("Perimeter of rectangle is : "+perimeter);
  }
```

Comment: `'a'` for perimeter and `'p'` for area?

Comment: sorry typed to fast

Comment: I wouldn't answer a question like this one, its not clear at all what his problem is. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267540/dont-answer-bad-questions

Comment: It was asked just recently, maybe he clarifies it. I usually wait before flagging. Not sure if thats good practice or not.

Comment: @whitemaple There should really be a more flexible mécanisme for akswering simple question like that with proposition. Comments are too short and with noneasy formatting